# Creating a Service To Return a List

Tags: c#, wcf

Within my **Service1.svc** file I have the following;

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Accounts> GetAllAccounts()
{
    string Conn = "......";
    List<Accounts> Accs = new List<Accounts>();

    SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(Conn);
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SQL QUERY....", _con);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    _con.Open();
    reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) { Accs.Add(new Accounts() { Name = reader["Name"].ToString(), Qty = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Qty"]), Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Weight"]), Value = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Value"]) }); }
    _con.Close();

    return Accs.ToList();
}

public class Accounts
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I know that my SQL is correct and I have printed the contents of this List to screen to ensure the data is there, the problem I have however is when I try to run the service in my browser - it fails.

Now, I believe this is because my **IService.cs** is conflicting with the returned 'List' control. The error I get is;

My Service1.GetAllAccounts() method cannot implement my IService1.GetAllAccounts() because it doesn't have the matching return type of 'System.....List'.

IService1.cs;

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    List<Accounts> GetAllAccounts();
}

public class Accounts
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

This issue sounds very simple, but I'm fairly new to C#, could anyone advise?

Comment: how and when do you receive this error?

I have just copied your code and put it into a new WCF application and it works fine...

I am obviously just return new List<Account>() in my concrete...

Comment: @SecretSquirrel The error appeared on my VS console on build - Steve's code has resolved this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attribute to your Accounts class

```
[DataContract]
public class Accounts
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Also, the client code that uses the Service should be configured to receive as Collection Type a System.Collection.Generic.List

Right click the Service Reference and select "Configure Service Reference". In the Collection Type combo select System.Collection.Generic.List instead of the default Array

Just for completeness, as others have already said, it makes no good to have two class with the identical names Accounts. This will only confuse the compiler to the point to receive an error. And you have already created a List variable so, return just that variable.

Comment: Thanks. The code now builds, but when I 'view in browser' I get the following error.. The OperationContractAttribute declared on method 'GetAllAccounts' in type 'NameSpace.Service1' is invalid.

Comment: Remove the OpearationContract attribute from the concrete method that  that implements the IService1.GetAllAccounts

Comment: @Clev231 Did you update the generated proxy class ? Right click on the referenced service > Update the service reference

Answer (score 2):

The error you get, of which you omitted the relevant parts, shows the issue:

> My Service1.GetAllAccounts() method **cannot implement my IService1.GetAllAccounts()** because it doesn't have the matching return type of '**System.....List**'.

You have two `Accounts` classes, one in your service interface and one in your implementation. They are probably in different namespaces too. So your interface contains a method:

```
List<Accounts(FromInterface)> GetAllAccounts();
```

And your implementation has a method:

```
List<Accounts(FromImplementation)> GetAllAccounts()
```

This causes your error, because `List<Accounts(FromInterface)>` is not `List<Accounts(FromImplementation)>`.

Create your `Accounts` class in a different file and make sure interface and implementation refer to the same `Accounts` type.

Comment: Thanks - Good answer and I understand the issue now.

Comment: surely this would not build if the concrete did not match the interface?

Comment: @SecretSquirrel well the question shows this exact compilation error. And don't call me Shirley.

Comment: @CodeCaster By the way, they were in the same namespace, just thought it might be of interest.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes Im sorry, I had the lasagna.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Accounts> Accs = new List<Accounts>();
```

Accs is already a List object so,

```
return Accs.ToList();
```

should be

```
return Accs;
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the type returned by the service can only be an array (`Accounts()`)

Hit `F12` (Go to definition) on your function `service.GetAllAccounts();` and you will notice that it return an `Accounts()`, as opposed to a `List<Accounts>`.

Just call `service.GetAllAccounts().ToList;` and it should solve your problem.

Also, You don't need to redeclare the `Accounts` class in your `Service1.svc.cs` since it's already in the interface `IService.cs`.

Edit: You might need to implement your class too:

```
public List<Accounts> GetAllAccounts() : IService1 {
    ...
}
```